# Mysql Alter command how to alter the existing table to add the primary key

Tags: mysql

I have table name persons,

```
CREATE TABLE Persons (
    P_Id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    FirstName varchar(255),
    Address varchar(255),
    City varchar(255)
)
```

Now i am planning to add the primary key on column 2 Lastname, so i tried alter command:

```
ALTER TABLE Persons
ADD CONSTRAINT pk_LastName PRIMARY KEY (LastName)
```

When i run the alter command i have error message: 1068 Multiple primary key defined.

Could you please help me how to fix this ?

Thanks,
Palani

Comment: You already have a primary key (in the table definition).  You would need to drop this first, before you can create a new PKey.

Comment: Are you sure you need a new primary key? Maybe you just need to add another unique key.

Comment: first you drop existing primary key then you can add another primary key.

Comment: Hi Barmar, I dropped the primary key, then i added primary key two column's now it is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER TABLE `Persons`   
CHANGE `LastName` `LastName` VARCHAR(255) CHARSET utf8 COLLATE utf8_danish_ci NOT NULL, 
DROP PRIMARY KEY,
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`P_Id`, `LastName`);
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have a primary key on the table.  Don't define another one.  Instead, you can add a unique constraint on those columns:

```
ALTER TABLE Persons ADD CONSTRAINT unq_lastname UNIQUE (LastName);
```

However, this seems dangerous, because different people can have the same last name.